# concurrent access to array without safety

Tags: java, concurrency

field values is float[] and I'm litte confused beacause when I debug code I run on issue that when one thread is working and using my float[] values array other are waiting it's normal? I don't care about wrong data on array because threads are computing different part of array

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

List<PartOfImage> callables;
        for(int j=0;j<200;++j)
        for(int i=0;i<threads;++i){
            callables=new LinkedList<>();
            callables.add(new PartOfImage(values,width,(height/threads)*i, (height/threads)*(i+1),
                    oldImage,((i+1)%threads)==0,(i%threads)==0));

        List<Future<Object>> answers =   executor.invokeAll(callables);


         oldImage=getValues();
        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your executor. If it's a single-thread executor, it will run the tasks serially, not in parallel.

Comment: Ok, I've added it.

Comment: What is the definition of  `getValues();` ? you must be using `Future.get()` I assume, in that case the call is blocking.

Comment: Each logical core can only run one thread at a time, all the others have to wait. I suggest using parallel stream to schedule this more efficiently.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, my processor has 4 cores and 8 threads. So can I run 8 threads using executor or 4 ? Because you're saying cores...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `threads` is 10. You probably think your code produces 10 callables in the `callables` list and then runs `invokeAll`. But in fact, your code executes this whole block for each `i`:

```
callables=new LinkedList<>();
callables.add(new PartOfImage(values,width,(height/threads)*i, (height/threads)*(i+1),
              oldImage,((i+1)%threads)==0,(i%threads)==0));

List<Future<Object>> answers =   executor.invokeAll(callables);
oldImage=getValues();
```

Which means it creates a list with one callable, and runs `invokeAll` on that list, then goes to the next `i`, creates a list with one callable, runs `invokeAll` on that (single-task) list, and so on.

So in effect it runs serially. Your should move the creation of the list outside of the `i` loop, only the `callables.add` should be inside the loop, and the `invokeAll` and `getValues` should be outside it.